# Group Settings in Mavericks Profile Manager

Tags: macos, server.app, profile-manager

I have successfully setup my Mavericks server with Profile Manager.
I have enrolled my devices and all is working fine.

(For example) I have a group with 40 users in it. I want to apply Calendar (CalDAV) settings to that group.
It asks me to enter the username and password for the user. It's a group....

Is there a way to add the settings as a "template" and the user only has to add there username and password?
I assumed that when the user enrols the device, they have to authenticate to the /mydevices page, so it already has the users credentials?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are variables you can enter for common user fields

http://krypted.com/mac-security/using-payload-variables-in-profile-manager/